# What to do about posts that are edited to include comments/partial answer/etc

Tags: discussion, edits, flags

Occasionally I run into posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7110119/834176), where responses to the answers are edited into the original question. Sometimes the answer is even copied into the body of the question, or other things are said which are more appropriate for comments. It's like the asker's don't understand that the existing system, which allows for voting, accepting, commenting and answering your own question, already allows for this is a much cleaner fashion.

What should I do about such posts? Edit them? I don't necessarily want to utterly destroy what the user said, so I feel like I should flag it for a moderator, who (maybe?) can turn it into comments or something. But if so, what flag should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag for moderators "other" and type in your recommendations about what to do with the post.  For example, the added stuff in the question could be comments or merged with the accepted answer.  The long thread of comments in the accepted answers could probably be merged into the answer, too.

Ideally, we want to have a clear question, and a clear answer; and both should be easy to read.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a user-level action; any one with enough rep can edit the questions and answers, as well as leave a comment to the effect that the poster shouldn't do that.  Using a moderator flag, while possible should only be used as a last resort if you don't have the ability to do it yourself.